# Shell exec file runs in background process ???

Tags: php

Using ShellExec process, I have run a file with one argument. arguments we will get from a single txt file. That txt file has more than 75000 lines. So that file will run 75000 times. At that time, will the server handle that process???

Comment: So, you're running a shellexec process for _each_ line that's in the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

yes the server should handle the process, if it takes too long you can set

```
php_value max_execution_time 120 #seconds
```

in .htaccess

**Normally you use a database for so much data.**